# When is __declspec(dllimport) used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllexport

When I want to create a .dll-File in Visual Studio (c++) I use the following code in the Header-File:

```
#ifdef MYPROJDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYPROJDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYPROJDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

I use "MYPROJDLL_API" as a macro to mark functions of the class that have to be exported. Visual Studio creates the definition of "MYPROJDLL_EXPORTS" automatically in the project settings. I ask myself why I have to create an if-statement because "MYPROJDLL_EXPORTS" is defined by Visual Studio on build by itself, so that the else-branch is never triggered on building.

Comment: Have you read documentation?

Comment: Yes. "MYPROJDLL_EXPORTS" is only defined during compiling. When another program use the .dll, the else-branch ist triggered. But if I use only dllexport, my program is also compiled fine and runs.